# sublime text 4 customize prediction

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext4

Sublime text 3 had a dropdown menu that suggested previously used variables, which I really liked. While sublime text 4 still does that it also shows additional code snippets, which I find very annoying. Hence, is there a way to only show used variables in the prediction?

For example, in the picture below, I don't want a prediction of a function or class:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I was just blind. All that is needed is:

```
"auto_complete_include_snippets": false
```